# Rails toggle attribute dynamically

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I'm trying to toggle user attributes without making individual methods for each attribute I want to toggle:

```
  def toggle
    item = params[:item]
    id   = params[:id]
    @user = User.find(id)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update("#{item}": !@user."#{item}")
        flash[:success] = "Success!"
        format.js {render template: "admin/toggle_admin"}
      else
        flash[:error] = "Problem toggling"
      end
    end
  end
```

I think it's just a syntax issue. This clearly won't work...but how do I toggle a user's attribute where the attribute is dynamic?

Further, is it a good idea, or possible to toggle an attribute for any class? This would allow me to use jquery switches universally through the app with one method.

Comment: Does "toggling" mean that this is strictly limited to switching booleans to the opposite value, or are you trying to create a controller action that dynamically sets any kind of attribute?

Comment: @BrentEicher, yes I should have mentioned that. Only for Boolean attributes.

Comment: Are you wanting to blindly toggle switches or specify explicit values?

Comment: @BrentEicher, I want to toggle to the opposite of whatever was set. ie. if `is_admin` is true for the user, the operator can click a toggle switch and toggle the field for that user.

Comment: To clarify, are you wanting to send something like @user.switch_item and trust that a true will become a false, or provide an argument like this: @user.switch_item_to('true')

Comment: More like `toggle_user_path(@user, "item_to_toggle")` using a link_to

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95082/discussion-between-kevin-brown-and-brent-eicher).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would move this toggle logic into the model, and you can abstract it into a module if you want to use it in different models. You can accomplish the dynamic behavior you want just by passing an argument to the method. For example:

```
class User

  def toggle(attribute)
    current_value = self.send(attribute)
    self.update_attribute!("#{attribute}", !current_value)
  end

end
```

From the controller you would call @user.toggle('foo') and it will make the switch, throwing an exception if it fails.

If named methods would better serve your JQuery switch, you could try some metaprogramming:

```
class User
  SWITCHES = %w(foo bar baz)

  SWITCHES.each do |switch|
    define_method("toggle_#{switch}") do
      toggle("#{switch}") 
    end
  end

  private

  def toggle(attribute)
    current_value = self.send(attribute)
    self.update_attribute!("#{attribute}", !current_value)
  end
end
```

For each instance of the User class, a method will be created for each attribute you specify as a switch. They all share common functionality, so I've abstracted a private method that everyone calls.

From the controller you would call @user.toggle_foo and it will make the switch.

According to the link you are wanting, here's what a controller might look like:

```
class ToggleUserController

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    if @user.toggle(params[:switch])
      flash[:success] = "Success!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      flash[:error] = "Problem toggling"
    end
  end
end
```

And your route:

```
patch ":user_id/relevant_path", to: "toggle_user#update", as: :toggle_user_path
```

And the link:

```
link_to "Foo", toggle_user_path(@user, switch: 'foo'), method: :patch
```

You should probably:

- Safeguard against accidentally toggling a non-boolean attribute
- Ensure that booleans are given default values, as this code won't do anything with nil

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it

1. If you want to update dynamic attributes with any value then

   ```
   respond_to do |format|

       if @user.respond_to? item
           @user.send("#{item}=", value)
           @user.save

           flash[:success] = "Success!"
           format.js {render template: "admin/toggle_admin"}
       else
           flash[:error] = "Problem toggling"
       end
   end
   ```
2. If you just want to toggle boolean values e.g from false to true and vice versa then

   ```
   respond_to do |format|

       if @user.respond_to? item
           @user.toggle(item)
           @user.save

           flash[:success] = "Success!"
           format.js {render template: "admin/toggle_admin"}
       else
           flash[:error] = "Problem toggling"
       end
   end
   ```
3. If you are using mongoid you can do

   ```
   @user.update_attribute item.to_sym, !@user[item.to_sym]
   ```
4. and this should also work

   ```
   @user[item] = !@user[item]
   @user.save
   ```

Comment: Does mongodb have a `.toggle` method??

Comment: Rahul, for whatever reason, this gem isn't working for me...I don't think this is a solution.